# AppendChild only html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append Html as a child to a  Element, i tried:

```
$.each(data, function(i, field){
    var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    tbody.appendChild('<tr><td>'+ field.name +'</td><td>' + field.vorname + '</td><td>' + field.geburtsdatum + '</td><td>' + field.strasse + '</td><td>' + field.plz + '</td></tr>');
});
```

But somehow i get this error:

```
 Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
```

How can i fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

appendChild() takes a node as the argument, try jQuery's append() instead

```
var $tbody = $('tbody').eq(0);
$.each(data, function (i, field) {
    $tbody.append('<tr><td>' + field.name + '</td><td>' + field.vorname + '</td><td>' + field.geburtsdatum + '</td><td>' + field.strasse + '</td><td>' + field.plz + '</td></tr>');
});
```

---

As Json said, it is best to create the html first then append it, so try

```
var array = $.map(data, function (field, i) {
    return '<tr><td>' + field.name + '</td><td>' + field.vorname + '</td><td>' + field.geburtsdatum + '</td><td>' + field.strasse + '</td><td>' + field.plz + '</td></tr>';
});

$('tbody').eq(0).append(array.join(''));
```

Comment: @JohnSmith I would note that it's more efficient to actually append the content to the DOM only once after the loop completes instead of on each iteration.